# Get WooCommerce Total Sales Dollar Amount (revenue)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there anyway to get WooCommerce total sales dollar amount, I'm using [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-total-sales-shortcode/) and it's shortcode for this purpose but I'm looking for a way to get the **today's total revenue amount** (gross sales) without using a plugin. I'm gonna use that code inside another plugin that I'm developing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
    $Select_Order_Details = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SUM(meta.meta_value) AS total_sales, COUNT(posts.ID) AS total_orders FROM wp_posts AS posts

    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta ON posts.ID = meta.post_id

    WHERE meta.meta_key = '_order_total'

    AND posts.post_type = 'shop_order'

    AND posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", array( 'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold' ) ) . "' )");



    $Select_Order_Details = json_decode(json_encode($Select_Order_Details),true);
    print_r($Select_Order_Details);exit;
```